# Room - Deleting a Table and Resetting its Primary Key

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I want to delete all the entires in the table before adding new ones and reset the PrimaryKey back to 1.

This is my Entity

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
private int weatherId;
private String highTemp;
private String lowTemp;
```

So i used

```
if(weatherEntries != null && weatherEntries.size() != 0){
        Log.d(TAG, "WeatherEntry List is not empty");
            mDb.clearAllTables();


            for(int i = 0; i < weatherEntries.size(); i++) {
                mDb.weatherDao().insertWeather(weatherEntries.get(i));
                Log.d(TAG, "Inserting Weather Data into the Database");
            }
        }
```

When the new entries are added their primary key doesn't start from 1.
So, I have tired to query

```
@Query("ALTER TABLE SequenceAction AUTO_INCREMENT = 0")
void clearPrimaryKey();
```

I get the error

> "error: no variable alternative at input 'SequenceAction AUTO_INCREMENT'"

I tried to look google on how to solve this and even looked at the Android Documentation of Room as how to reset the primary key but haven't found anything.

Any Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this query:

```
 @Query("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 1 WHERE name = <table>")
void clearPrimaryKey();
```

as table will be for your table name, for example:

```
 @Query("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 1 WHERE name = 'WHEATHERS'")
void clearPrimaryKey();
```

Comment: I tried to add the line "
@Query("DELETE FROM weather_data")
    void deleteFullTable();

    @Query("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 1 WHERE name = 'weather_data'")
    void clearPrimaryKey();"

i am able to delete the table but the primary key doesnt reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two queries:

```
delete from your_table;
```

and

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = <n> WHERE name = 'your_table'
```

This will do the trick. `n`  is 1 in your case. ID will start again at 1.

Comment: I tried to add the line 
"@Query("DELETE FROM weather_data")
    void deleteFullTable();"

"@Query("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 1 WHERE name = 'weather_data'")
    void clearPrimaryKey();"

i am able to delete the table but the primary key doesnt reset.